# How to calculate the 4 pairs of latitude and longitude that bound a city programmatically?

Tags: dictionary, latitude-longitude, openstreetmap

I've been researching ways to implement offline maps on iPhone using OpenStreetMap (with CloudMade tile server).  I'd like to be able to allow users to request for offline maps based on a given city name (e.g. San Francisco, CA).  The tile server http interface suggests that I'd need to know the range of latitudes and longitudes covering the given city.  Is this feasible?  How do I calculate this programmatically?

Comment: Do you intend to have your own OSM database or just a static tile server?

Comment: @IgorBrejc do I need OSM or a static tile server?  I am using CloudBase's tile server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CloudBase tile server, do you have any reference links?

Comment: http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/tiles/documents

Comment: CloudBase != CloudMade. CloudMade is a commercial OSM provider. CloudBase is a "is a high-performance data warehouse system built on top of Map-Reduce architecture" (http://cloudbase.sourceforge.net). You should be more careful when writing your questions.

Comment: Just edited the question.  Sorry about the confusion!